# Local variable to global variable in JS for loop, value changed after loop ends

Tags: javascript, loops

Curious about why i becomes 5 in the end?

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log('A: ', i);
}
console.log('B: ', i);
```

Comment: `i = 4` -> `i < 5 === true` -> `console.log('A: ', i);` -> `i++` -> `i = 5` -> `i < 5 === false` -> end loop.

Comment: var i gets hoisted.  It's equivalent to var i; for(i=0;i<5;i++) console.log(i); console.log(i)

Comment: because at end it becames 5 and the condition becomes false and it breaks and console.log B where I = 5

Comment: @NinaScholz How do you guys find these dupes?  Makes me feel like I don't know how to use Google anymore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i++` increases the value of `i` at the end of each loop.

The loop goes round until the condition (that `i` is 4 or less) isn't true.

When `i` is 5, that is the first time the condition isn't true.